# How do I make all URLs in my S3 bucket inaccessible for public browsing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a chat application running on an RHEL server that uploads files exchanged between users to an S3 bucket. How do I restrict access to these files to only users who are using the application, but at the same time also allow anyone using the server's SSH terminal and the code on that server to get those files?

I realize that I can restrict access to a specific HTTP referrer or IP address as shown in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html). However, this restricts access for either the application server or the application users. Is there a way I can combine these two policies?

So the bottom line is that I don't want anyone apart from the users using the application and the server hosting the application to access these files on S3.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's the bucket policy if anyone has a similar problem -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "RestrictAccessPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "52.12.34.56"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests referred by referrer",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http://yourwebsite.com/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referer.",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http://yourwebsite.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```